# Change the display of date format in error/valiadtion messages in laravel 8.x +

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

validator with rule
`date_format:d`

gives me the unreadable

> The :attribute does not match the format :format.

e.g.

> birth day does not match the format d

now a user is not a developer, they won't understand what is `d`

I saw you can use your own replacer somehow here

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/b9203fca96960ef9cd8860cb4ec99d1279353a8d/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ReplacesAttributes.php#L68

the question is, how to properly overwrite that function?
how to get your own proper validator?

Comment: Have you looked at https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#customizing-the-error-messages? You should be able to do something like `$messages = ['birth_date.date_format' => 'Birth Date must be a number between 01 and 31']` (since `d` is  "Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros")

Comment: yes I forgot to mention, I understand that you can do that.  But that is a punctual fix, not a global one. You understand what I mean? `d` is never a good translation ever. So this should be changed application wide, not on a per field basis.

Comment: Ah ok I see what you're saying; instead of `:format` being `d`, or `Y-m-d`, etc, you want a more "user-friendly" message, like `01 to 31`, or `2022-03-16`. Can't say that's something I've ever had to do, but I can see the benefit.